# Отображать страницу в зависимости от прав

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Подскажите, как правильно выдавать пользователю страницу в зависимости от его прав.
Например, у одной роли одни кнопки, а у другой другие.
Столкнулся в одном проекте с тем, что в разметки в большом кол-ве мест встречается условие if, где перебираются роли => если нужно поменять отображение интерфейса у конкретной роли, то придется это править в N мест, а не в одном месте.

Как лаконично решаются подобные задачи?

Comment: А как вы видите решение? Сделать для каждой из ролей свою страницу? А если вам верстку надо поменять, дублируетесь на каждую из страниц ролей?

Comment: @AGS17, под каждую из ролей тоже, наверное, не совсем корректно... Так как придется поддерживать много страниц. Может быть через частичные представления?

Comment: и как вы собираетесь дробить эти паршалы?

Comment: @AGS17, вы намекаете на то, что практика, которая описана в вопросе- это нормально и от этого не уйти?

Comment: в большинсве случаев - да. Видел практики, когда дописывали экстеншены, но это применимо только на отдельные контролы (такие как линки, например)

Comment: @AGS17, хм... тогда получается много кода, который дублируется и при добавлении новой роли или изменении существующей придется править много мест на странице+ монстроозные лесенки из if.

Comment: Приведите может пример ваших if-лестниц, я не могу сейчас себе реального примера с такой лестницей представить.

Comment: @AGS17, возможно, я немного преувеличил. Однако, так или иначе если меняется у роли то, что она должна видеть, то приходитеся править в нескольких местах код, который как правило дублируется

Comment: по мне самый оптимальный вариант написать какой нибудь хелпер или экстеншн, который будет генерировать эти кнопки через switch

Comment: @iluxa1810 если вы собираетесь часто менять роли, могу предложить раздробить их на пермишены: рендерить или не рендерить контрол будет определять этот пермишн. Каждая из ролей будет содержать списки пермишенов, которые необходимо рендерить.

Answer (score 0):

Если одному пользователю может соответствовать только одна роль, то на каждую страницу вешается список ролей, которым она будет предоставлена.

Если одному пользователю может соответствовать несколько ролей, то на каждый элемент управления вешается список ролей, которым он будет предоставлен.

Пересекающиеся по ролям элементы отдаются пользователю, не пересекающиеся - не отдаются.

Можешь рассматривать это с точки зрения файловой системы, где роли - группы пользователей, папки - страницы, а файлы - элементы управления.